# FFmpeg preserving 360 video orientation

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, metadata

I am using FFmpeg (version 2022-03-24) to convert dual fisheye 360 video recorded on a Rylo camera into equirectangular format. My goal is to stitch videos in bulk on the PC instead of using the Rylo Android app and avoid dealing with large video files on my phone. At this point I’ve got it stitching at an acceptable quality level.

What I’m losing in the conversion is the "always upright" orientation that is preserved when the Rylo Android app processes the same raw dual fisheye source file. I’m thinking that the dual fisheye source .mp4 file contains some metadata that the Android app is able to read. **How can I make sure that the camera orientation data is processed when FFmpeg stitches that same source file?**

In other words, as I record 360 video and turn the camera sideways or upside down the Android app will always stitch the output with the ground at the bottom. I’m not getting that to happen when I process the video with FFmpeg and so post processing is tedious when the camera is on a selfie stick and I have to keep manually adjusting the orientation.  I want the video to remain upright no matter where I position the selfie-stick.

See the attached image and linked video examples.

[image]

In case you are curious, here are the commands I’m using to convert raw Rylo video files into equirectangular. I'm using the roll method to set the initial orientation. My ask in this request to to maintain the orientation after that.

```bat
REM Create a merge map for blending the edges between the front and rear cameras.
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i nullsrc=size=2016x2016 -vf "format=gray8,geq='clip(128-128/(6)*(180-192/(2016/2)*hypot(X-2016/2,Y-2016/2)),0,255)',v360=input=fisheye:output=e:ih_fov=192:iv_fov=192,format=rgb24" -frames 1 -y mergemap.png

REM Convert the video from dual fisheye to equirectangular while applying the mergemap created in the first step.
ffmpeg -i RYLO0054.MP4 -i mergemap.png -profile:v High -pix_fmt yuv420p -lavfi "[0]format=rgb24,split[a][b];[a]crop=ih:iw/2:0:0, v360=input=fisheye:output=e:ih_fov=192:iv_fov=192:roll=90[c]; [b]crop=ih:iw/2:iw/2:0,v360=input=fisheye:output=e:yaw=180:ih_fov=192:iv_fov=192:roll=90[d]; [c][d][1]maskedmerge,format=rgb24" -y RYLO0054_eq.MP4 

REM Here is a simpler single-line command that doesn't blur the seam lines.
REM If you have an answer you respond using this format as an example.
ffmpeg -i RYLO0012.mp4 -vf v360=dfisheye:e:ih_fov=192:iv_fov=192:roll=-90 -y RYLO0012_eq.mp4
```

Here is a video example
https://youtu.be/l1Evob6MQvA

edit:  Added ffprobe output from a raw Rylo .mp4 file.
[image: ffprobe output image]

Comment: Check the original video with `ffprobe` to get an idea which stream contains the data, use `-map` to copy the data stream when processing

Comment: @mashuptwice I've added the ffprobe output to the question.  An error is generated when it processes the "Rylo Media Handl" stream.  I'm guess that stream contains the every changing orientation data.  Am I out of luck?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any media with metadata stream at hand to test it, could you try adding `-c:d copy` or `-map 0 -c:d copy`?

Comment: @mashuptwice neither of those options worked.  I'm making a sample file available so you can experiment with.   https://www5.zippyshare.com/v/fnoTXXN7/file.html
`ffmpeg -t 5 -i RYLO0012.mp4 -vf v360=dfisheye:e:ih_fov=192:iv_fov=192:roll=-90 -y RYLO0012_1.mp4`

Comment: I've extracted the metadata stream with `ffmpeg -i RYLO0012.MP4 -map 0:d -c copy -copy_unknown -f data raw.bin`. Still don't know what to do with it. I also could not find anything about if ffmpeg supports positional data of 360° videos.

Comment: I've noticed that the metadata contains hexadecimal data with chunks of 4 digits/16 bit. `0000` is recurring after each 10th chunk. The next 2-3 chunks are increasing in value from `0003
e6eb 3c70` at the beginning (after probably 6 chunks of header), to `0005 d75f d778 ` at the end of the file. It looks like timestamps to me. That leaves 6 unidentified chunks; my guess: 3 x 16ibt for a gyroscopes XYZ output and 3 x 16bit for a magnetometers or accelerometers XYZ. I have absolutely no idea if there is any standardization or docs for 360° cameras metadata, but it certainly caught my interest!

Comment: Wow!  That's quite a deep analysis.  Is there any chance you know someone who can make a filter for FFmpeg to process that?